# Locking down Systems in a Computer Lab School for Orphans

Tags: installation, administration, cybercafe, kiosk

I am helping out an NGO, called Orphans Found Fund, here in Arusha Tanzania setup a computer lab to teach students about Ubuntu and open source applications. I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 on all the systems. What I'm wondering about is how to tweak the systems so that the kids cannot:

- Delete or alter system files
- Alter the system settings
- Add or remove applications
- Exceed a time limit (like an Internet Cafe)

  Also as the administrator I would like to monitor the usage for another system to make sure that abuse of network is not taking place. Any advice is much appreciated. Brendon

Comment: 1,2 & 3 are done if you Set up  a "GUest account", i'm not sure but i think there is a screenlet (widget) to monitor bandwidth usage.

Comment: Have you considered setting Ubuntu up as a kiosk?

Answer (score 7):

- Delete or alter system files
- Alter the system settings
- Add or remove applications

To do any of these you need the `sudo` password. So after installing your system you have your own account and start creating normal users. Do not tell them the `sudo` password and they can not alter these. All they can do is change values in their own home.

If you want total control install [ACL](http://packages.ubuntu.com/acl) [image: Install acl]

(wiki: [access control list](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions#ACLs))

`guest` login takes care of these too. Logging in as a guest will lock down anything important. But I think you would not want this if you want to track who was responsible for altering something. `guest` will make everything show up as altered by `guest`. I would set up useraccont instead so you could see based on user if someone created something.

- Exceed a time limit (like an Internet Cafe)

My favourite method would be a `cron` script that checks uptime and shuts down after reaching a threshold. Command for shutdown after 120 minutes:

```
sudo shutdown -h 120
```

If you put that in a script and put it into `cron` with `crontab -e` it would kill the machine after 2 hours.

Mind you... you will get into trouble with your users if this happens when they have some unsaved content or a website open they wanted to bookmark before the system quits.